# Unable to login with Google plus using omniauth-google-oauth2

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth, google-authentication, spree-auth-devise

I am using gem "omniauth-google-oauth2"  in my application built on spree(ruby-on-rails)  to integrate Google plus login on to our site.I am getting a very strange error here,It's working fine in development(localhost),
 but in production I am getting this error

"auth/google_oauth2/callback?state=35ad3c2e3f8327a5b96df7ce7e2439a77b90dfebc41f8463&code=4/p5l-nug7FU3P8lfnSHNF8Uy_tYXcLyqc0bnABoGo0EI#".

For integrating Google plus ,I have done following

a.) I created a WebApplication App in google developers console by adding necessary javascript origin and redirect url's

b.) I have added client id, secret in my coonfig file
OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do

provider :google_oauth2, 'my cient id', 'secret'

end

c.) I have added a route  'auth/google_oauth2/callback'

I am really struck here for quiet some time.

Comment: have you added production url in google console?

Comment: Yes  Gagan,  I have added it

Answer (score 0):

I have done google-omniauth-oauth2 for quite a few apps.

Based on my experience I am giving you some hints.

Some of the possible reasons could be

1. You have added ur production url to google console, but may have missed out on callback url for production.
2. Check for routes and see if you have added a callback route. Normally it should point to method 'sessions#create' in your SessionsController.

Try the following in omniauth.rb

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, 'GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID', 'GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET
  {
      :access_type => 'offline',
      :prompt => 'consent'
  }
```

Here is my sessions#create method for your reference

```
    def create
        auth = request.env['omniauth.auth']
        @user = User.find_by_email(auth.info.email) || User.create_with_omniauth(auth)
        if !@user.country
          @user.country = request.location.country
        end
        @user.update_tokens auth
        reset_session
        session[:user_id] = @user.id
        redirect_to new_video_path, :notice => 'Signed In!'
   end
```

For more help check [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/rails-authentication-oauth-2-0-omniauth/) link.

Comment: Thanks for your reply vipul,
I verified points 1 and 2 and changed my omniauth.rb file accordingly
But I am getting same error



auth/google_oauth2/callback?state=94fef1d37b059a495f93ad5901f0499ea250dc903f7ed6fd&code=4/8KmdToVb86NMLIAjB_yTXWM9TagJ8vAktQuWzIK7Dg0#

Comment: @ShakthiSadras I just looked into your error again and tried it in my app. This is not an error you are getting. once session is created you need to direct user to some page, which you don't seem to be doing. At the end of your 'sessions#create' method just put a redirect_to some_path. for eg root_path.

Comment: @ShakthiSadras I have edited my answer. refer to last line and the error would go.

Comment: Thanks for your reply again. I am using the same function 'create' as you mentioned in your comment. But unable to login still, when I check my production logs I am seeing that function session#create is not getting called at all

Comment: @ShakthiSadras it is not an error. You need to either create a view for session#create. I am sure you have note done that. Or  on success you should redirect to another view.

Comment: As  mentioned above , I am using spree, I used the same functionality  and integrated facebook , but  when i use the same for gmail it's not working
 This is the route I am using
 "get 'auth/google_oauth2/callback', to: 'user_registrations#gmail'"

And this is the function


def gmail
  
    user = Spree::User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    if user
      sign_in(:spree_user, user)
      session[:spree_user_signup] = true
      associate_user
      redirect_to "/"
     end